# Binary conversion code Segmentation fault

Tags: c, pointers, binary, segmentation-fault

I am new to programing in C (only 2 weeks into it). I am unable to figure out why my code is throwing a segmentation fault. I am able to get the program to work if I set long int num equal to a static number. However I need the program to be able to accept user input from the command line (not once the program is running)

Example:
./binary 7

should output
The binary number for 7 is: 111

I have tried using strcpy(num, argv[0]) but that also throws errors when compiling.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include<math.h>

void decToBinary(long int num)   // Function Definition
{
    long int remainder[50];
    int i=0;
    int length=0;
    printf("The binary number for %d is: ",num);
    while(num > 0)
     {
             remainder[i]=num%2;    // does the mod function
             num=num/2;             // Divides original number by 2
             i++;                   // Increases count for the upcoming for-loop
             length++;              // Increases length display digits
     }
    for(i=length-1;i>=0;i--)        // Prints out the binary number in order (ignoring the previous 0's)
    {
            printf("%ld",remainder[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");                   // Adds a new line after the binary number     (formatting)
}
//================================================================================================
int main(char argc, char* argv[])
{
    long int num;                           //HOW DO I TAKE ARGV[0] AND MAKE IT A USEABLE VARIABLE???

    printf("Enter the decimal number:  ");  //TEMPORARY until problem above is solved
    scanf("%ld",&num);                      //TEMPORARY until problem above is solved

    decToBinary(*num);                      // Calling decToBinary function
    return 0;                               // Program terminated successfully
}
```

Comment: If you're new to C, then your very first fatal error is that you're discarding the return value of `scanf`. Your second fatal error is that you are ignoring your compiler's warnings, or worse, didn't instruct your compiler to warn you about obvious errors (such as `*num`).

Comment: [Ideone](http://ideone.com/ZWw0cX) gives up on your code for three unrelated reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Hint1: If you want to change `num`'s value inside `decToBinary()`    function, you have to pass its address in it. So you should call it    like this:

```
decToBinary(&num);
```

Then your function's prototype would look like this:

```
void decToBinary(long int *num)
```

So you have to modify the function's body properly too. I guess that's what causes the Segmentation Fault.

---

Hint2: `argc` stands for arguments count, so its type isn't `char` but `int`.

---

As *@Kerrek SB* pointed out on his comments, [`scanf(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf) is a function with a return value of type `int`. It's considered wise to check the return value and handle any possible error that may occur.

---

`argv[0]` is the name of the executable. If you want to use the first argument from your command line, it's stored in `argv[1]`, and it's of type `char *`. So if you want to use it as a number, you can use one of [these](http://linux.die.net/man/3/atoi) functions of `stdlib.h`.

Comment: The atoi seems to be what I need, how would I impliment that into the code to take the first argument and store it, so I would be able to pass it into the decTobinary function? is it as simple as adding "int atoi(const char *num) = argv[1]; to the code instead of the "long int num;"?

Comment: @user3701193 If you want `num` to be of type `long` as it is now, then you need the function `atol`. It would be used like this: `long num = atol(argv[1]);`. Also mind to `#include <stdlib.h>`.

Comment: I guess what im messing up (constantly) is the pointers and dereferencing. The atol seemed to work nicely, but the error is in the mod operation now. [link](http://ideone.com/mPlIQF)

Answer (score 0):

Something like (does not handle some error situations)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

void decToBinary(long int num)   // Function Definition
{
    long int remainder[50];
    int i=0;
    int length=0;
    printf("The binary number for %ld is: ", num);
    while(num > 0)
     {
             remainder[i]=num%2;    // does the mod function
             num=num/2;             // Divides original number by 2
             i++;                   // Increases count for the upcoming for-loop
             length++;              // Increases length display digits
     }
    for(i=length-1;i>=0;i--)        // Prints out the binary number in order (ignoring the previous 0's)
    {
            printf("%ld",remainder[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");                   // Adds a new line after the binary number     (formatting)
}
//================================================================================================
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if (argc > 1)
    {
        long int mylong = atol(argv[1]);
        decToBinary(mylong);                      // Calling decToBinary function
    } else
    {
        int errno = 0;
        long int num;                           
        int res;

        printf("Enter the decimal number:  ");  //TEMPORARY until problem above is solved
        res = scanf("%ld",&num);                      //TEMPORARY until problem above is solved

        if (res != EOF)
        {
            decToBinary(num);                      // Calling decToBinary function
        } else
        if (errno != 0)
        {
            perror("scanf");
        } else
        {
            printf("No number found in input\n");
        }
    }

    return 0;                               // Program terminated successfully
}
```

** I'm building this on Ubuntu 14.04 **

Note that decToBinary(*num) is wrong. You would only use the dereference operator on a pointer not an int or any non pointer type.

A pointer holds an address in memory and when you dereference it you are telling your program to read at that address. If you were dereferencing an int value of for example 10, you are telling the program to read a value at address 10. This is a very low address value and will be outside of the memory range that your programme is allowed to access and so it will be a segmentation fault.

Firstly you must pay attention to compiler warnings. If applicable use the -Werror and possibly -Wextra flags when you build your executable.

e.g
    gcc -g -Werror -Wextra myfile.c -o myfile

This is a good opportunity to learn to use a debugger to find your segfault, if you are serious about C programming its essential knowledge. Note above the -g flag which builds debug symbols into your executable (without the symbols the debugger wont know the function names). You can then use gdb (or another debugger as applicable) and launch your executable, then run it and get a back trace to tell you when the segfault happens.

Answer (score 0):

A simple method of extracting the `argv[1]` parameter to its constituent bits and displaying those bits...

```
// following eliminates any nonnumeric char from input
// by stopping at first nonnumeric char
long int value = atol(argv[1]);  
int position = sizeof( long int ) -1;

// following loop could be modified/prefixed with a loop to skip leading 0's
for( ; position >= 0; position-- )
{
    printf( "%c, ", ('0' + ( value >> position) & 1) );
}

printf( "\n" );
```